# Compare a list of strings to Model values and get the corresponding field

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I have a Permissions class for which I need to create a static method to get the corresponding element based on the POST method in my `views.py`. The choices are done via checkboxes, in which you can select either of those, a pair or all of them, based on your preferences. That creates a list of strings (u'OWNER'), which should be processed in the static method and return the corresponding `Permissions.OWNER`, `Permissions.HR`, `Permissions.USER_ADMIN`

My `views.py`'s `POST` method looks like this:

```
permissions = self.request.get_all('permissions') 
user.new_permission = Permissions.get_permission(permissions)
```

Model looks like this:

```
class Permissions(object):
    OWNER = 'OWNER'
    HR = 'HR'
    USER_ADMIN = 'USER_ADMIN'

descriptions = {
    OWNER: """Company owner (full admin)""",
    HR: """Human Resources administrator (access to special fields within job and submissions)""",
    USER_ADMIN: """Add/Delete users, change user permissions""",
}
```

What I have so far on the static method:

```
@staticmethod
def get_permissions(permissions):
    new_perms = []
    for permission in permissions:
        name = permission
        if permission == 
        new_perms.append(permission)
    return new_perms
```

I really do not know how can I compare a string to the value in the model... Nor I am sure if I have titled the question correctly.

Thank you in advance,

Borislav

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of things wrong with your code, and it seems to be overcomplicated.
I suggest you do some python tutorials.  I m not sure how the class definition was ever going to work.  Any way here is one way you could do it.

```
class Permissions(object):

    _perms = {
        'OWNER': """Company owner (full admin)""",
        'HR': """Human Resources administrator (access to special fields within job and submissions)""",
       'USER_ADMIN': """Add/Delete users, change user permissions""",
    }

    @classmethod
    def get_permissions(cls,permissions):
        new_perms = []
        for choice in permissions:
            if choice in cls._perms:
                new_perms.append(choice)

        return new_perms

    @classmethod
    def get_description(cls,permission)
        return cls._perm.get(permission)
```

Actually on re-reading your question I am not sure what you are really trying to do. You mention a model, but the permissions class you provide doesn't reflect that, and I assume you need to query for the object. In fact if you where using a model to define permissions you would have a Permission object for each possible Permission - maybe.

alternate strategy, but there are many and without looking in more detail at how you really plan to use permissions.  (I use repose.who/what for a fairly well developed permission model). At its most basic you can use getattr with your existing class. However I not keen on it, as there are no checks in place.

```
class Permissions(object):
    OWNER = 'OWNER'
    HR = 'HR'
    USER_ADMIN = 'USER_ADMIN'

    @classmethod
    def get_permission(cls,permission):
        if hasattr(cls,permission):
            return getattr(cls,permission)
        else:
            raise KeyError("No permission %s" % permission)  # Some better exception should be used.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for the bad explanation. You are correct, the Permissions class gathers all the Permission objects (that are custom to each company, another model). So my question is how can I get a corresponding Permission from the Permissions class (one I explained) by having checked the boxes on the template. They are called/used by Permissions.NAME (so Permissions.USER_ADMIN, Permissions.HR etc) in other parts of the code and they give you certain privileges (to add users etc). I get the list of checked items, but how do I map them to the right permission?

Comment: See additions to answer.  Again these are fairly basic python techniques.